# Blackberry, Barry Desktop, UBUNTU 14, OpenSync

Tags: blackberry

I have a Blackberry Playbook. I downloaded Barry Desktop from software centre. I tried to use Barry, but it is asking me for OpenSync library. I have looked all over the internet and have no idea how to get it.

What I would like to do is backup my playbook, add music and videos and to add apps that I have developed.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out OpenSync's [download page](http://www.opensync.org/wiki/download)? "All/most opensync packages are available in Debian testing/unstable and Ubuntu Hardy." ...where Hardy equals versions beyond Ubuntu 8.04. You may need to tell Ubuntu that you want [access to more repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

My blackberry is french so not sure of the name of the files.

On your BB:
- Go to parameters / Storage and acess
- here you have to enable Wifi access
- Change the wifi password
- Then click on network information to get your domain name and user name.

Then connect with USB your BB to the computer.

On the computer:
- Clic on your file directory
- Then clic on "Parcourir le réseau" in french so maybe "explore the network" ?
- Explore the different directories (there's one named "windows network" ?)
- Find your Blackberry directory and clic on it, a pop up will ask you your User name, Domain name and password you found and changed on your BB.

Then it works for me.